# Replace href several strings in vb.net asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to find several hrefs in html like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="url1">link1</a></td>
<td><a href="url2"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Once found I need to add (replace) to each href something like this:

```
?ID=1
```

therefore the html should turn out like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td><a href="url1?ID=1">link1</a></td>
<td><a href="url2?ID=1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new code:

```
Shared Function AdjustURL(ByVal psInput As String, ByVal psAppend As String) As String
    Dim sOrig As String = " " & psInput 'Prepending a space (browser will ignore) in case the first character is a link.
    Dim sOutput As String = ""
    Dim iEnd As Integer = -1, iQuestion As Integer = -1

    While sOrig.Length > 0
        sOutput &= sOrig.Substring(0, 1)
        sOrig = sOrig.Substring(1)
        iEnd = -1            
        If sOrig.StartsWith("<a href=") Then  'Is this a safe assumption, what if it's not an <a> or href isn't next after only one space?
            If sOrig.StartsWith("<a href=""") Then
                iEnd = InStr(10, sOrig, """")  'URL ends with a Quote
            Else
                iEnd = InStr(9, sOrig, " ")   'URL ends with a Space - are there other possibilities?
            End If
            iQuestion = InStr(sOrig, "?")
            If iQuestion > iEnd Then iQuestion = -1
            sOutput &= sOrig.Substring(0, iEnd - 1) & IIf(iQuestion > -1, "?", "&") & psAppend
            sOrig = sOrig.Substring(iEnd - 1)
        End If
    End While
    Return sOutput

End Function
```

Call:

```
Dim sHTML As String = "<table> <tr><td><a href=""url1"">link1</a></td> <td><a href=""url2""><img src=""image.jpg"" /></a></td> </tr> </table>"
Response.Write(Class1.AdjustURL(sHTML, "ID=1"))
```

Result:

```
 <table> <tr><td><a href="url1?ID=1">link1</a></td> <td><a href="url2?ID=1"><img src="image.jpg" /></a></td> </tr> </table>
```

I'm sure there will be other replacements you will discover over time as users enter things.  I'd definitely recommend replacing `<script` with something like `<span style=display:none` to avoid javascript injection.  You'll also want to be sure to avoid SQL injection before writing this to your database.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I am afraid that its not that simple since I do not know the value of href!

I therefore (1st) have to itenerate the whole HTML, (2nd) find all strings starting with href" (and ending with ") (example = href="url1"), (3rd) alter them and (4th) put them back in place (example = href="url1" becomes href="url1?ID=1").

But I like I said above: I have no clue what the User inserts as Href.

Mike

Comment: In the last chunk of code, it suggests concatenating another binder, but you could certainly concatenate "?ID=" & request("targetid").ToString...or ddlValue.selectedValue or wherever you want to get the data - though I would recommend sanitizing the value before using it. 

Per your comment, it looks like you are interested in treating the whole page as a string and doing that replacement. You could capture the render event into a string and do the requisite replacements. 

That sort of thing was great in classic ASP but nowadays, jQuery might be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, the whole Html has to be treated as one.

This is actually not about Page Html but Html inserted by the User into a DB and updated when send as a Newsletter.

When the Newsletter is send several QueryStrings have to be added to each individual hrefs.

I do not work with jQuery, maybe you could provide me with some help doing it the old way :).

Comment: OK, so the HTML to be modified is entered by a user. Good clarification - thanks! Since you have a string you could walk through each character in the string looking for likely URLs (.StartsWith("href=")) but there are a LOT of different ways a user can enter a URL - with or without quotes, with or without additional parameters (? might already be in the URL so you might need &).  I'll post some code that should at least get you started.

Comment: I assume you've already turned off the feature where ASP.NET won't let users post HTML back.  Once you do that, you had better be very careful that they didn't enter any javascript that could be dangerous!

Comment: Wow, thats a lot of code, many thanks.

I am out of the office for the next couple of days but will try to understand and adopt your code till next Monday.

Many thanks again, talk soon, Mike.